# For loop not working in React when using setState (DOM not showing up updated data)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's up friends,

I have a problem. I have DOM elements that show data from the variable (useState) that I am saving with some "accounts".

I have a function that updates the data of each element by calling the api, and I have a function that refreshes all the elements one by one, the problem is that when using the function that refreshes all the elements, the changes are not reflected correctly in the dom but when using the function individually (I have a button for that) I can see the changes correctly reflected.

I do not get the error, if you can help me I would be very grateful.

Refresh Function

```
let [accounts, setAccounts] = useState

const refreshAccount = async (id, name, token) => {
    await setIsBusy(true)
    await updateWorkingStatus(id, true, name, token)
    let work = await axios.get(
      'http://192.168.0.101:3000/account/refresh/' + id,
    )
    await updateWorkingStatus(id, false, name, token)
    await setIsBusy(false)

    // console.log(work.data.result)

    let accs = [...accounts]
    let index = accs.findIndex((acc) => acc._id === id)

    accs[index] = work.data.result
    accs[index]._id = id

    // console.log(accs[index])

    setTimeout(() => {
      setAccounts(accs)
    }, 0)
    return 'OK'
  }
```

Refresh Selected Item (I already have a function that selects each item and works nice)

```
  const refreshSelected = async () => {
    let finalAccounts = await accounts.filter((acc) => acc.selected)
    for (let i = 0; i < finalAccounts.length; i++) {
      await refreshAccount(
        finalAccounts[i]._id,
        finalAccounts[i].name,
        finalAccounts[i].token,
      )
    }
  }
```

I know the problem is updating the status, but I can't solve it. Implement a setTimeout and the previous element to the last is updated or the last of the cycle, the previous ones are left with the outdated data (first state).

I think problem is when using FOR loop on React, but dont know how to use it correctly

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @JBaczuk ok sorry, post updated

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that the `setAccounts` function is asynchronous, but the execution doesn't wait for it to complete. Because `setAccounts` is asynchronous, subsequent calls in the same update cycle will overwrite previous updates, and the previous changes will be lost, causing only the last update to take effect.

You could store the changes to an array and update it after all the API requests have finished.

```
let [accounts, setAccounts] = useState

const refreshAccount = async (id, name, token) => {
    await setIsBusy(true)
    await updateWorkingStatus(id, true, name, token)
    let work = await axios.get(
      'http://192.168.0.101:3000/account/refresh/' + id,
    )
    await updateWorkingStatus(id, false, name, token)
    await setIsBusy(false)

    // console.log(work.data.result)

    let accs = [...accounts]
    let index = accs.findIndex((acc) => acc._id === id)

    accs[index] = work.data.result
    accs[index]._id = id

    return accs
  }
```

```
const refreshSelected = async () => {
    let finalAccounts = await accounts.filter((acc) => acc.selected)
    let newAccounts = []
    for (let i = 0; i < finalAccounts.length; i++) {
      const accs = await refreshAccount(
        finalAccounts[i]._id,
        finalAccounts[i].name,
        finalAccounts[i].token,
      )
      newAccounts = newAccounts.concat(accs)
    }
    setAccounts(newAccounts)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you!, that workaround is nice i did try to use it, but at the end of the loop i only get the first element updated, really weird. Also thought about this workaround but the problem there is that theis taks takes time, and i need to display update data in the DOM while the other tasks are getting done, not at the end but this is useful too

Comment: To update between each api call, you need to keep track of the API calls in the component state so each one happens on a new render cycle.